# Virtualbox installation dependency failure on Ubuntu 18

Tags: virtualbox

For version 6 i get this message:

```
virtualbox-6.0 : Depends: libqt5opengl5 (>= 5.0.2) but it is not installable
                  Recommends: libsdl-ttf2.0-0 but it is not installable
```

**ubuntu software center / synaptic have version 5 though 6 exists and no version 5 or 6 gets installed**

For version 5 i get this message:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:


virtualbox-qt: Depends: virtualbox (= 5.2.18-dfsg-2) but 5.2.18-dfsg-2 is to be installed
               Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:3.0) but 1:8.2.0-7ubuntu1 is to be installed
               Depends: libqt5core5a (>= 5.11.0~rc1) but 5.11.1+dfsg-7ubuntu1 is to be installed
               Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.4.0) but 5.11.1+dfsg-7ubuntu1 is to be installed
               Depends: libqt5opengl5 (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libqt5widgets5 (>= 5.11.0~rc1) but 5.11.1+dfsg-7ubuntu1 is to be installed
               Depends: libqt5x11extras5 (>= 5.6.0) but 5.11.1-2 is to be installed


**from synaptic manager, i get this message**

virtualbox:
 Depends: virtualbox-dkms but it is not going to be installed or
    virtualbox-source but it is not going to be installed or
    virtualbox-modules
 Depends: libgsoap-2.8.60  but it is not installable
 Depends: libvncserver1 (>=0.9.10) but it is not installable
 Recommends: virtualbox-qt but it is not going to be installed
 Recommends: libqt5opengl5 (>=5.0.2) but it is not installable
```

apt-cache policy virtualbox virtualbox-qt virtualbox-5.2 virtualbox-6.0
OUTPUT

virtualbox:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 5.2.18-dfsg-2
  Version table:
     5.2.18-dfsg-2ubuntu18.10.1 -1
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     5.2.18-dfsg-2 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic/multiverse amd64 Packages
virtualbox-qt:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 5.2.18-dfsg-2
  Version table:
     5.2.18-dfsg-2ubuntu18.10.1 -1
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     5.2.18-dfsg-2 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic/multiverse amd64 Packages
virtualbox-5.2:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 5.2.26-128414~Ubuntu~bionic
  Version table:
     5.2.26-128414~Ubuntu~bionic 500
        500 http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian cosmic/contrib amd64 Packages
virtualbox-6.0:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 6.0.4-128413~Ubuntu~bionic
  Version table:
     6.0.4-128413~Ubuntu~bionic 500
        500 http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian cosmic/contrib amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

Comment: Please add outputs of `apt-cache policy virtualbox virtualbox-qt virtualbox-5.2 virtualbox-6.0` to the question.

Comment: Looks like you don't have the `cosmic-updates` repo enabled. Three of those packages I checked are older versions. Be sure you have `cosmic-security` enabled also. Do you have a specific preference which version of Virtualbox you want? Or is the Ubuntu default okay?  The most common reason for this kind of problem is a wrong-version or non-Ubuntu source. Not every deb is compatible with every version of Ubuntu..

Comment: apt-cache policy virtualbox virtualbox-qt virtualbox-5.2 virtualbox-6.0 PRINTS
virtualbox:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 5.2.18-dfsg-2
  Version table:
     5.2.18-dfsg-2ubuntu18.10.1 -1
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     5.2.18-dfsg-2 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic/multiverse amd64 Packages
virtualbox-qt:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 5.2.18-dfsg-2
  Version table:
     5.2.18-dfsg-2ubuntu18.10.1 -1
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     5.2.18-dfsg-2 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic/multiverse amd64 Packages

Comment: virtualbox-5.2:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 5.2.30-130521~Ubuntu~bionic
  Version table:
     5.2.30-130521~Ubuntu~bionic 500
        500 https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian bionic/contrib amd64 Packages
virtualbox-6.0:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 6.0.8-130520~Ubuntu~bionic
  Version table:
     6.0.8-130520~Ubuntu~bionic 500
        500 https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian bionic/contrib amd64 Packages
     6.0.4-128413~Ubuntu~bionic -1
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

```
apt --fix-broken install
```

Hopefully that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading it off there website here;
https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads

Then click `Ubuntu 18.04 / 18.10 / Debian 10`

Run the file that downloads. The one on the Ubuntu Software center did not work for me to. But that one did

Comment: i already did that :(

Comment: it cannot get installed

Comment: Whats the error message that is showing up? If there is one.

Comment: in short words i always get the message, cannot locate and install packages libqt5opengl5 or libsdl-ttf2.0-0 even after adding the "right" repositories

Answer (score 0):

### Is the version of libqt5core5a, you have a old version, you need inistall this library and reinstall it.

```
apt remove libqt5core5a
apt remove libqt5core5a
apt install -f virtualbox-qt


  eading state information... Done
libqt5core5a is already the newest version (5.15.2+dfsg-2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
root@Odoo-Dev:/home/jrmpacheco# apt remove libqt5core5a
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libdouble-conversion3 libpcre2-16-0 qttranslations5-l10n
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libqt5core5a
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 6 058 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 206732 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing libqt5core5a:amd64 (5.15.2+dfsg-2) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.1) ...
root@Odoo-Dev:/home/jrmpacheco# apt install libqt5core5a
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libqt5core5a
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 2 005 kB of archives.
After this operation, 6 015 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 libqt5core5a amd64 5.12.8+dfsg-0ubuntu1 [2 005 kB]
Fetched 2 005 kB in 5s (417 kB/s)             
Selecting previously unselected package libqt5core5a:amd64.
(Reading database ... 206721 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libqt5core5a_5.12.8+dfsg-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libqt5core5a:amd64 (5.12.8+dfsg-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libqt5core5a:amd64 (5.12.8+dfsg-0ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.1) ...
root@Odoo-Dev:/home/jrmpacheco# apt install libqt5core5a
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libqt5core5a is already the newest version (5.12.8+dfsg-0ubuntu1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
root@Odoo-Dev:/home/jrmpacheco# apt install libqt5core5a
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libqt5core5a is already the newest version (5.12.8+dfsg-0ubuntu1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
root@Odoo-Dev:/home/jrmpacheco# apt install qtbase-abi-5-12-8
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libqt5core5a' instead of 'qtbase-abi-5-12-8'
libqt5core5a is already the newest version (5.12.8+dfsg-0ubuntu1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
root@Odoo-Dev:/home/jrmpacheco# apt install -f virtualbox-qt
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libqt5dbus5 libqt5gui5 libqt5network5 libqt5opengl5 libqt5printsupport5 libqt5svg5 libqt5widgets5 libqt5x11extras5
  libxcb-xinerama0 libxcb-xinput0 qt5-gtk-platformtheme
Suggested packages:
  qt5-image-formats-plugins qtwayland5
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libqt5dbus5 libqt5gui5 libqt5network5 libqt5opengl5 libqt5printsupport5 libqt5svg5 libqt5widgets5 libqt5x11extras5
  libxcb-xinerama0 libxcb-xinput0 qt5-gtk-platformtheme virtualbox-qt
0 upgraded, 12 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 28.5 MB of archives.
After this operation, 86.2 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
```

[VirtualBox on Ubuntu 20.04 lts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGC8g.png)